# Extra xmlns in xml generated from xmlserializer

Tags: .net, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

I have generated a class from a schema via the xsd.exe tool

Now when I serialize the class I get an extra `xmlns=""` on everything below the root.

```
<myroot xmlns="blabla">
    <tag1 xmlns="">
        <tag2>
            ...
```

The schema looks like:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="blabla" targetNamespace="blabla" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="MyRoot">
```

I can't see anything in the schema indicating that the tag1 element and below should be in another namespace than the root.

The serialization code just does:

```
MyRoot doc = new MyRoot();
...
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRoot));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
try {
    xs.Serialize(ms, doc);
```

The class generated from xsd.exe only contains a namespace attribute on the root class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What it's doing here is overriding the namespace `"blabla"` from the parent element with a specific namespace `""`.**

The reason it's doing here is because `tag1` has an empty namespace set (or it implicitly infers it has an empty namespace) and that `myroot` has the namespace `"blabla"`.

The solution is to make sure that `tag1` has the same namespace as `"blabla"`.

I know, this is very irritating because it means you have to provide the namespace again and again, but that's how it works.

Comment: So in a schema you must specify the namespace explicitly on all elements (except the root)? Didn't know that, thanks.